# Rollback command not working - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus, rollback, dml

I dropped a table and tried to rollback, but to no use. Will it ever work like this or am I playing wrong here?

As from most of the comments I am clear that DDL statements cannot be undone by rollback but only by FLASHBACK.

I tried undoing 
       DELETE FROM STUDENT;

It still it can't be undone:

My order of execution was

- INSERT,
- DELETE FROM ,
- ROLLBACK.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711447/oracle-ddl-and-transaction-rollback

Comment: please don't shove the solution in the question

Comment: @Sathya I dont have enough reputation to answer my own question . So i updated here  to let my commenters know that the question is resolved otherwise they would have to wait 8 hours and some of them surely has burned their time by then  solving the same question . You must have considered this fact before voting down and editing my answer .   For me i did the right thing and guess what  !! now ,i have to write my answer again from the scratch .  I guess i should thank you !

Comment: @kushal 1. Section above is meant for questions, not answers. 2.  downvote was for poor formatting and a crappy question with no details at the start 3. You can leave a comment saying you got it fixed/will update in 8 hours or whatever time 4. Your "answer" is not lost, always available from the previous revisions list.  http://i.imgur.com/RxLCQ.png http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8942034/revisions

Comment: @Sathya...  You really must read the comment flow below . Initially,i was not even aware that if we can rollback a dropped table !  And thanks to the commentors for making me clear .  And for that what details could i have provided initilally MR . sathya   ?  God bless your intelligent mind Mr . moderator .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ROLLBACK` without a savepoint qualifier will roll back the entire current transaction.

For DDL statements, there is no current transaction to rollback.  The DDL statement implicitly generates a `COMMIT` before the statement starts and after it completes.  So if you issue a `ROLLBACK` following a `DROP`, no work has been done in the current transaction so there is nothing to roll back.

For DML statements, you'll roll back the entire current transaction.  If you do

- INSERT
- DELETE
- ROLLBACK

your transaction begins when you execute the `INSERT` operation.  So when you issue the `ROLLBACK`, you are rolling back both the `INSERT` and the `DELETE` so you're back to having no data in the table (assuming you started with no data).  If you `COMMIT` after the `INSERT` then the next transaction would begin with the `DELETE` and your `ROLLBACK` will only roll back the `DELETE` operation.  Alternately, you can declare a savepoint after the `INSERT` and roll back to the savepoint

```
SQL> create table foo( col1 number );

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo values( 1 );

1 row created.

SQL> savepoint after_insert;

Savepoint created.

SQL> delete from foo;

1 row deleted.

SQL> rollback to savepoint after_insert;

Rollback complete.

SQL> select * from foo;

      COL1
----------
         1
```

Comment: Hey man , i have one more problem regarding dropped tables and i posted it  too but till now haven't found a solution . Can you please see it . here is the link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937093/dropped-table-not-showing-up-in-recycle-bin)

Answer (score 13):

I don't believe rollback will undo schema changes.

Comment: Correct. DDL statements cannot be rolled back in Oracle

Comment: @climbage  Can it undo the deleted rows from table ?

Comment: Could you provide us with the statements which you use and the exact order in which you executed them? You can rollback a data manipulation (like deletion of rows) as long as you don't execute a commit or perform structural changes (like dropping tables) in the database. Rollback only works back in time until it hits one of such events, no further.

Comment: @Kosi2801 . i have updated my question and i haven't committted anything.

Comment: Does your database client have autocommit enabled? Check that it doesn't automatically performs a commit after each successful statement!

Comment: @Kushal: Not only can you not roll back DDL, you can not roll back DML that happens prior to DDL. DDL does an implicit commit, performs the action, and another implicit commit, all within one statement.

Answer (score 4):

Rollback does not undo schema changes, but to undo drop table operations you can check:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/flashptr004.htm

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_1001.htm#i2099120):

> Oracle Database implicitly commits the current transaction before and after every DDL statement.

This means that you cannot `ROLLBACK` a DDL statement (that is, a schema change).

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer is helpful for the specific question as it requires more knowledge on the concepts of structure and transactions, which are obviously not yet clear to the questioner.

Comment: @Kosi2801@ajx   yeah ! it wasn't an appropriate answer but info is helpul .

Answer (score 2):

Rollback will never undo Data Definition commands such as drop table alter table etc.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping a table changes the **structure** of the database (using [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) statements like CREATE, DROP, ...).

COMMIT and ROLLBACK only work on the **data** which is exchanged with the database using [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) statements (like INSERT, UPDATE, ...).

So, no it will never work like this.

Answer (score 0):

To rollback ddl changes you need to use Flashback.

Answer (score 0):

Rollback:

Discard all pending changes by using the ROLLBACK statement. Following a ROLLBACK statement:

- Data changes are undone.
- The previous state of the data is restored.
- The locks on the affected rows are released.

Example

While attempting to remove a record from the TEST table, you can accidentally empty the table. You can correct the mistake, reissue the proper statement, and make the data change permanent.

```
DELETE FROM test;
25,000 rows deleted.

ROLLBACK;
Rollback complete.

DELETE FROM test
WHERE id = 100;

1 row deleted.

SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE id = 100;
No rows selected.

COMMIT;
Commit complete
```

After giving commit we can't rollback.

Comment: `After giving commit we can rollback.` ==> You mean we *cannot* rollback, rather it's pointless because the transaction has already been closed.