# Table doesn't exist on db that was created via python

Tags: python, oracle, create-table, cx-oracle, ora-00955

I used the following code to create a table in python.

```
import cx_Oracle as db

conn = db.connect('scott/tiger@localhost/orcl')  
cursor = conn.cursor()  
cursor.execute("create table films(title varchar(10), year varchar(10), director varchar(10))")  
print("table created")
```

but when i tried to access the table from SQLplus it says that the table doesnt exists.
when tried to run the code again i got the error

> "cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object"

what went wrong here.

I just started to learn python. your help is much appreciated.

Comment: It does _not_ say that the table doesn't exist. It says that the _"name is already used by an existing object"_, i.e. the table _exists_. You only need to create it once...

Comment: @Ben: Ah, [Oracle DDL is indeed not transactional](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711447/oracle-ddl-and-transaction-rollback). I'll remove the comment.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you are using 2 different  databases