# Using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE inside PL\SQL Block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ddl, dml

Using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE inside PL\SQL block makes the whole block commit immediately.

```
begin 

INSERT INTO Customer ( GUID, STATUS, NAME) VALUES (1,1,'xx');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE Shop
(
  GUID         NUMBER(16),
  STATUS       NUMBER(1),
  NAME         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
)
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DONE:'); 

EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN  -- handles all other errors 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error occured, rollback...'); 

 ROLLBACK;
end;
```

As you realized I do not even use COMMIT. About above code,

"Insert into" statement works, but "create table" statement throws exception because there is already a table with the same name in the database.

Both I did not have any commit statement and code block fell exception and rolled back when I looked at the database I saw that insert had worked and there was a new row. It was expected that it  should not have been there because there is no commit and also rollback worked..

How can I make rollback when exception occurs.

Comment: This is because DDL is not transactionnal in Oracle. See: [Oracle: DDL and transaction rollback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711447/oracle-ddl-and-transaction-rollback). `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` doesn't commit, but your `CREATE TABLE` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ty this PL/SQL Code:

```
begin 

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE Shop
(
     GUID         NUMBER(16),
     STATUS       NUMBER(1),
     NAME         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
)
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DONE:'); 

INSERT INTO Customer ( GUID, STATUS, NAME) VALUES (1,1,'xx');

EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN  -- handles all other errors 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error occured, rollback...'); 

ROLLBACK;
end;
```

So firstly it will create the table, if exception occurs it will rollback the transaction and insert statement will not work. Hope this will work for you..