# Problem in converting varchar2 column to clob data type in Oracle database

Tags: oracle, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-sql, liquibase-pro

I have one **Person** table in my database. I am using **Oracle** database. I have one column **ADDRESS** which has **varchar2** datatype. I want to change datatype of this column from **varchar2** to **clob**. I am doing this change by **Liquibase**. Here is my change set.

```
<changeSet id="15" author="shivam">
    <sql>
        ALTER TABLE PERSON ADD ADDRESS_CLOB VARCHAR2(2040 CHAR);
        ALTER TABLE PERSON MODIFY ADDRESS_CLOB LONG;
        ALTER TABLE PERSON MODIFY ADDRESS_CLOB CLOB;
        UPDATE PERSON SET ADDRESS_CLOB = ADDRESS;
        ALTER TABLE PERSON DROP COLUMN ADDRESS;
    </sql>
    <rollback>
        ALTER TABLE PERSON DROP COLUMN ADDRESS_CLOB;
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

By above changeset I will be able to convert from **varchar2** to **clob**. But as you can see that my final column name is **ADDRESS_CLOB**. But my requirement is final column name should be **ADDRESS** and it should be of **clob** datatype. How can I do that please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to rename the column with:

```
alter table person rename column address_clob to address;
```

Note that in [Oracle Database DDL is not transactional like in other databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711447/oracle-ddl-and-transaction-rollback).

Comment: If I will write your command inside changeset then there will be several problems. You need to also take care of if this command will fail then how are you going to rollback.

Comment: Please detail problems: database problems ? which error messages ? Liquibase problems ? If you have already tested this and this failed please edit your question with relevant ouput.

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what did you not understand?

Comment: If you don't detail "problems" no one can really help you here.

Comment: Your solution will work but I am writing migration script in Liquibase and If your sql query fails then how will I rollback. If you don't understand then I can clarify again.

Comment: There is nothing to rollback explicitely: in Oracle all DDL commands run in their own transaction: if an ALTER statement fails it will automatically be rolled back by Oracle.

Comment: Yes you are right But If I will add your command in my changeset at last. And suppose all the commands succeeded and yours one failed then your command will rollback but impact will be that In my database I will have one column with name `ADDRESS_CLOB` with `CLOB` data type which is result of previously succeeded commands. Which I don't want because I said that I want `ADDRESS` column in the end with `CLOB` data type.